# Finding shortest path using Prolog

Tags: prolog, shortest-path

I have read a few tutorials about this topic but I still don't understand.

Code:

```
%flight(ORIGIN,DEST,DEPARTTIME,ARRIVALTIME,FLIGHTNO, DAY). Day 1=mon 7=sun
flight(singapore,london , 2310, 0520, ba58,1).
flight(singapore,london , 2310, 0520, ba58,3).
flight(singapore,london , 2310, 0520, ba58,4).
flight(singapore,london , 2310, 0520, ba58,6).
flight(london,singapore , 1000, 1610, ba24,1).
flight(london,singapore , 1000, 1610, ba24,3).
flight(london,singapore , 1000, 1610, ba24,4).
flight(london,singapore , 1000, 1610, ba24,6).
flight(london,edinburgh , 0940, 1050, ba4732,1).
flight(london,edinburgh , 0940, 1050, ba4732,2).
flight(london,edinburgh , 0940, 1050, ba4732,3).
flight(london,edinburgh , 0940, 1050, ba4732,4).
flight(london,edinburgh , 0940, 1050, ba4732,5).
flight(london,edinburgh , 0940, 1050, ba4732,6).
flight(london,edinburgh , 0940, 1050, ba4732,7).
```

How do I find the fastest flight from say Singapore to Edinburgh?

Shortest flight calculation should include the total flight duration and total waiting time in between flights.

Comment: i wanted to try.. but don't even know where to start...

Comment: what book do you use? what is your last working code? (you can put it on pastebin.org or something). I'm asking, to know what do you know about Prolog at this time.

Comment: codes: http://pastebin.com/ca02QDfK
tutorial used: http://www.csupomona.edu/~jrfisher/www/prolog_tutorial/2_15A.pl

i could only do the simplest... the direct flights....

Comment: "code", when used as "computer program", does not have a plural (like for example "fish", or "sheep".

Comment: i tried to implement the an logic but it does not seem to work.. the prolog output a no at the end..

updated code: http://pastebin.com/pd0nG8XA

Comment: I would suggest a breath-first-search as inspiration: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breath_first_search

Answer (score 2):

```
%flight(ORIGIN,DEST,DEPARTTIME,ARRIVALTIME,FLIGHTNO, DAY).
flight(singapore,london , 2310, 0520, ba58,1).
flight(singapore,london , 2310, 0520, ba58,3).
flight(singapore,london , 2310, 0520, ba58,4).
flight(singapore,london , 2310, 0520, ba58,6).
flight(london,singapore , 1000, 1610, ba24,1).
flight(london,singapore , 1000, 1610, ba24,3).
flight(london,singapore , 1000, 1610, ba24,4).
flight(london,singapore , 1000, 1610, ba24,6).
flight(london,edinburgh , 0940, 1050, ba4732,1).
flight(london,edinburgh , 0940, 1050, ba4732,2).
flight(london,edinburgh , 0940, 1050, ba4732,3).
flight(london,edinburgh , 0940, 1050, ba4732,4).
flight(london,edinburgh , 0940, 1050, ba4732,5).
flight(london,edinburgh , 0940, 1050, ba4732,6).
flight(london,edinburgh , 0940, 1050, ba4732,7).
flight(london,edinburgh , 1140, 1250, ba4735,1).
flight(london,edinburgh , 1140, 1250, ba4735,2).
flight(london,edinburgh , 1140, 1250, ba4735,3).
flight(london,edinburgh , 1140, 1250, ba4735,4).
flight(london,edinburgh , 1140, 1250, ba4735,5).
flight(london,edinburgh , 1140, 1250, ba4735,6).
flight(london,edinburgh , 1140, 1250, ba4735,7).
flight(london,edinburgh , 1840, 1950, ba4822,1).
flight(london,edinburgh , 1840, 1950, ba4822,2).
flight(london,edinburgh , 1840, 1950, ba4822,3).
flight(london,edinburgh , 1840, 1950, ba4822,4).
flight(london,edinburgh , 1840, 1950, ba4822,5).
flight(edinburgh,london , 0830, 0940, ba4733 ,1).
flight(edinburgh,london , 0830, 0940, ba4733,2).
flight(edinburgh,london , 0830, 0940, ba4733,3).
flight(edinburgh,london , 0830, 0940, ba4733,4).
flight(edinburgh,london , 0830, 0940, ba4733,5).
flight(edinburgh,london , 0830, 0940, ba4733,6).
flight(edinburgh,london , 0830, 0940, ba4733,7).
flight(edinburgh,london , 1340, 1450, ba4736,1).
flight(edinburgh,london , 1340, 1450, ba4736,2).
flight(edinburgh,london , 1340, 1450, ba4736,3).
flight(edinburgh,london , 1340, 1450, ba4736,4).
flight(edinburgh,london , 1340, 1450, ba4736,5).
flight(edinburgh,london , 1340, 1450, ba4736,6).
flight(edinburgh,london , 1340, 1450, ba4736,7).
flight(edinburgh,london , 1940, 2050, ba4833,1).
flight(edinburgh,london , 1940, 2050, ba4833,2).
flight(edinburgh,london , 1940, 2050, ba4833,3).
flight(edinburgh,london , 1940, 2050, ba4833,4).
flight(edinburgh,london , 1940, 2050, ba4833,5).
flight(edinburgh,london , 1940, 2050, ba4833,6).
flight(london,greece , 0910, 1245, ba614,1).
flight(london,greece , 0910, 1245, ba614,2).
flight(london,greece , 0910, 1245, ba614,3).
flight(london,greece , 0910, 1245, ba614,4).
flight(london,greece , 0910, 1245, ba614,5).
flight(london,greece , 0910, 1245, ba614,6).
flight(london,greece , 0910, 1245, ba614,7).
flight(london,greece , 1445, 1820, sr805,1).
flight(london,greece , 1445, 1820, sr805,2).
flight(london,greece , 1445, 1820, sr805,3).
flight(london,greece , 1445, 1820, sr805,4).
flight(london,greece , 1445, 1820, sr805,5).
flight(london,greece , 1445, 1820, sr805,6).
flight(london,greece , 1445, 1820, sr805,7).
flight(greece,london , 0900, 1140, ba613,1).
flight(greece,london , 0900, 1140, ba613,2).
flight(greece,london , 0900, 1140, ba613,3).
flight(greece,london , 0900, 1140, ba613,4).
flight(greece,london , 0900, 1140, ba613,5).
flight(greece,london , 0900, 1140, ba613,6).
flight(greece,london , 1610, 1855, sr806,1).
flight(greece,london , 1610, 1855, sr806,2).
flight(greece,london , 1610, 1855, sr806,3).
flight(greece,london , 1610, 1855, sr806,4).
flight(greece,london , 1610, 1855, sr806,5).
flight(greece,london , 1610, 1855, sr806,7).
flight(london,paris , 0830, 1030, ba510,1).
flight(london,paris , 0830, 1030, ba510,2).
flight(london,paris , 0830, 1030, ba510,3).
flight(london,paris , 0830, 1030, ba510,4).
flight(london,paris , 0830, 1030, ba510,5).
flight(london,paris , 0830, 1030, ba510,6).
flight(london,paris , 0830, 1030, ba510,7).
flight(london,paris , 1310, 1510, az459,1).
flight(london,paris , 1310, 1510, az459,2).
flight(london,paris , 1310, 1510, az459,3).
flight(london,paris , 1310, 1510, az459,4).
flight(london,paris , 1310, 1510, az459,5).
flight(london,paris , 1310, 1510, az459,6).
flight(london,paris , 1310, 1510, az459,7).
flight(paris,london , 0910, 1020, ba511,1).
flight(paris,london , 0910, 1020, ba511,2).
flight(paris,london , 0910, 1020, ba511,3).
flight(paris,london , 0910, 1020, ba511,4).
flight(paris,london , 0910, 1020, ba511,5).
flight(paris,london , 0910, 1020, ba511,6).
flight(paris,london , 0910, 1020, ba511,7).
flight(paris,london , 1220, 1330, az460,1).
flight(paris,london , 1220, 1330, az460,2).
flight(paris,london , 1220, 1330, az460,3).
flight(paris,london , 1220, 1330, az460,4).
flight(paris,london , 1220, 1330, az460,5).
flight(paris,london , 1220, 1330, az460,6).
flight(paris,london , 1220, 1330, az460,7).
flight(paris,rome , 1130, 1240, jp322,2).
flight(paris,rome , 1130, 1240, jp322,3).
flight(paris,rome , 1130, 1240, jp322,4).
flight(rome,paris , 1330, 1440, jp323,2).
flight(rome,paris , 1330, 1440, jp323,3).
flight(rome,paris , 1330, 1440, jp323,4).
flight(rome,greece , 1440, 1630, fs619,1).
flight(rome,greece , 1440, 1630, fs619,3).
flight(rome,greece , 1440, 1630, fs619,4).
flight(rome,greece , 1440, 1630, fs619,5).
flight(greece,rome , 1100, 1310, fs620,1).
flight(greece,rome , 1100, 1310, fs620,3).
flight(greece,rome , 1100, 1310, fs620,4).
flight(greece,rome , 1100, 1310, fs620,5).


% Start menu
start :- repeat,nl,nl,
         nl, write('============================='), 
         nl, write(' FLIGHT ENQUIRY SYSTEM '),
         nl, write('============================='),
         nl, write('1) Preferred Direct'),
         nl, write('2) Preferred Fastest'),
         nl, write('3) Quit'),
         nl, nl, read(Option),
         option(Option).


% option 1 will terminate the program
option(1) :- nl, write('Please Day of Flight in Numberic format (1 for Mon, 7 for Sun: '), 
read(Day),
nl, write('Origin Country: '),
read(Origin), checkOCountry(Origin, 0), nl, write('Dest Country: '),
read(Dest), checkDCountry(Dest, 1)->
plane(Board,0),
plane(Arrive,1),
flightInfo(Board, Arrive,Start,End,FlightNo,Day),
calculateTime(Start,End, DH,DM),
nl,write('Flight No: '),write(FlightNo),
%checkDH(DurH,DurM), 
nl,write('Flight Dur: '),write(DH),write(':'),write(DM),
retractall(plane(X,Y)),!,fail.  

% option 3 will terminate the program
option(3) :- nl, write('Program has terminated!').


% check if a country is valid
checkOCountry(OCountry, Indicator) :- flight(OCountry,_,_,_,_,_) -> asserta(plane(OCountry, Indicator)); nl,write('Origin Country is invalid! Enter a valid Country: '), read(NewCountry),checkOCountry(NewCountry, Indicator).
checkDCountry(DCountry, Indicator) :- flight(_,DCountry,_,_,_,_) -> asserta(plane(DCountry, Indicator)); nl,write('Destination Country is invalid! Enter a valid Country: '), read(NewCountry),checkDCountry(NewCountry, Indicator).

flightInfo(Origin, Dest,Start,End, FlightNo,Day) :- flight(Origin, Dest,Start,End,FlightNo,Day).


calculateTime(Start, End, DH,DM):- OriMin is mod(Start, 100), DestMin is mod(End, 100), OriHour is (Start - OriMin)/100, DestHour is (End - DestMin)/100,
Y is DestHour - OriHour, X is DestMin - OriMin, 
(Y < 0 -> checkDH(OriHour, OriMin, DestHour,DestMin, DH, DM);
X < 0 -> checkDM(Y,X, DM, DH);
       DM is X, DH is Y
    ).

checkDM(Y, X , DM, DH):- DM is X + 60, DH is Y-1.
checkDH(OriHour, OriMin, DestHour,DestMin, DH, DM) :- THour1 is ((24-OriHour)+DestHour), TMin1 is 0-OriMin,
(TMin1< 0 -> THour is THour1 -1, TMin is ((60+ TMin1)+DestMin);
THour is THour1, TMin is TMin1
), 
(TMin > 60 -> DH is (THour + (TMin//60)), DM is mod(TMin, 60) ;
DH is THour, DM is TMin
).
```

Answer (score 2):

Branch and bound shortest path algorithm can be implemented with [restart](http://www.gprolog.org/manual/html_node/gprolog064.html). The algorithm doesn't use any dynamic database only backtracking and recursion. Lets say we have this graph:

[image]

Which we can be represented in Prolog as these facts:

```
% edge(-Vertex, -Vertex)
edge(a, b).         edge(a, c).
edge(a, d).         edge(b, c).
edge(c, d).         edge(c, e).
edge(d, e).
```

We first need a bounded path finder. This can be realized as a predicate that takes an upper bound, and then returns the number of hops subtracted from the upper bound, with the guarantee that the result is never below zero:

```
% path(+Vertex, +Vertex, +Integer, -Integer)
path(X, X, N, N).
path(X, Y, N, M) :- N > 0,
   H is N-1,
   edge(X, Z),
   path(Z, Y, H, M).
```

The bounded path finder is non-deterministic and uses backtracking for its search. We now add a further predicate that restarts the path finder by recursively using a smaller upper bound, whenever a path was found. This way the smallest length is found:

```
% bb_path(+Vertex, +Vertex, +Integer, -Integer)
bb_path(X, Y, N, M) :- N > 0,
   H is N-1,
   path(X, Y, H, K), !,
   L is H-K,
   bb_path(X, Y, L, M).
bb_path(_, _, N, N).
```

Note the use of a cut in the predicate branch and bound predicate. Here is an example run. We start with an upper bound which is the number of edges plus one. We can first manually call path/4 multiple times and simulate the search:

```
?- path(a, e, 7, K), L is 7-K.
K = 3,
L = 4 
?- path(a, e, 3, K), L is 3-K.
K = 0,
L = 3 
?- path(a, e, 2, K), L is 2-K.
K = 0,
L = 2 
?- path(a, e, 1, K), L is 1-K.
No
```

So starting with an upper bound 8, we gradually get better upper bounds 4, 3 and 2, until no more improvements are possible. The predicate bb_path/4 does this search for us:

```
?- bb_path(a, e, 8, X).
X = 2
```